# How to save images with correct orientation using CAMERA2

Tags: android, orientation, android-camera2

Here is my camera fragment, in which I am opening the camera using `TextureView`. The camera is capturing the image in correct orientation but the captured image is not getting saved in correct orientation...

```
public class Camera2BasicFragment extends Fragment
        implements View.OnClickListener, FragmentCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 1;
    private static final String FRAGMENT_DIALOG = "dialog";

    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
    }

    private static final String TAG = "Camera2BasicFragment";
    private static final int STATE_PREVIEW = 0;
    private static final int STATE_WAITING_LOCK = 1;
    private static final int STATE_WAITING_PRECAPTURE = 2;
    private static final int STATE_WAITING_NON_PRECAPTURE = 3;
    private static final int STATE_PICTURE_TAKEN = 4;
    private static final int MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH = 1920;
    private static final int MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT = 1080;
    private final TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener
            = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture texture, int width, int height) {
            openCamera(width, height);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture texture, int width, int height) {
            configureTransform(width, height);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture texture) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture texture) {
        }

    };

    private String mCameraId;
    private AutoFitTextureView mTextureView;
    private CameraCaptureSession mCaptureSession;
    private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;
    private Size mPreviewSize;
    private final CameraDevice.StateCallback mStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
            mCameraDevice = cameraDevice;
            createCameraPreviewSession();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
            cameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int error) {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
            cameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
            Activity activity = getActivity();
            if (null != activity) {
                activity.finish();
            }
        }

    };

    private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;

    private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
    private ImageReader mImageReader;
    private File mFile;
    private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener
            = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {

        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
            mBackgroundHandler.post(new ImageSaver(reader.acquireNextImage(), mFile));
        }

    };

    private CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewRequestBuilder;
    private CaptureRequest mPreviewRequest;
    private int mState = STATE_PREVIEW;
    private Semaphore mCameraOpenCloseLock = new Semaphore(1);
    private boolean mFlashSupported;
    private int mSensorOrientation;
    private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback mCaptureCallback
            = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

        private void process(CaptureResult result) {
            switch (mState) {
                case STATE_PREVIEW: {
                    // We have nothing to do when the camera preview is working normally.
                    break;
                }
                case STATE_WAITING_LOCK: {
                    Integer afState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE);
                    if (afState == null) {
                        captureStillPicture();
                    } else if (CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_FOCUSED_LOCKED == afState ||
                            CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_NOT_FOCUSED_LOCKED == afState) {
                        // CONTROL_AE_STATE can be null on some devices
                        Integer aeState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE);
                        if (aeState == null ||
                                aeState == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_CONVERGED) {
                            mState = STATE_PICTURE_TAKEN;
                            captureStillPicture();
                        } else {
                            runPrecaptureSequence();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case STATE_WAITING_PRECAPTURE: {

                    Integer aeState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE);
                    if (aeState == null ||
                            aeState == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_PRECAPTURE ||
                            aeState == CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_STATE_FLASH_REQUIRED) {
                        mState = STATE_WAITING_NON_PRECAPTURE;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case STATE_WAITING_NON_PRECAPTURE: {
                    // CONTROL_AE_STATE can be null on some devices
                    Integer aeState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE);
                    if (aeState == null || aeState != CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_PRECAPTURE) {
                        mState = STATE_PICTURE_TAKEN;
                        captureStillPicture();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCaptureProgressed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                                        @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                        @NonNull CaptureResult partialResult) {
            process(partialResult);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                                       @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                       @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
            process(result);
        }

    };

    private void showToast(final String text) {
        final Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (activity != null) {
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private static Size chooseOptimalSize(Size[] choices, int textureViewWidth,
            int textureViewHeight, int maxWidth, int maxHeight, Size aspectRatio) {

        List<Size> bigEnough = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Size> notBigEnough = new ArrayList<>();
        int w = aspectRatio.getWidth();
        int h = aspectRatio.getHeight();
        for (Size option : choices) {
            if (option.getWidth() <= maxWidth && option.getHeight() <= maxHeight &&
                    option.getHeight() == option.getWidth() * h / w) {
                if (option.getWidth() >= textureViewWidth &&
                    option.getHeight() >= textureViewHeight) {
                    bigEnough.add(option);
                } else {
                    notBigEnough.add(option);
                }
            }
        }

        if (bigEnough.size() > 0) {
            return Collections.min(bigEnough, new CompareSizesByArea());
        } else if (notBigEnough.size() > 0) {
            return Collections.max(notBigEnough, new CompareSizesByArea());
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't find any suitable preview size");
            return choices[0];
        }
    }

    public static Camera2BasicFragment newInstance() {
        return new Camera2BasicFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera2_basic, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view.findViewById(R.id.picture).setOnClickListener(this);
        view.findViewById(R.id.info).setOnClickListener(this);
        mTextureView = (AutoFitTextureView) view.findViewById(R.id.texture);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mFile = new File(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null), "pic.jpg");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startBackgroundThread();


        if (mTextureView.isAvailable()) {
            openCamera(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
        } else {
            mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        closeCamera();
        stopBackgroundThread();
        super.onPause();
    }

    private void requestCameraPermission() {
        if (FragmentCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
            new ConfirmationDialog().show(getChildFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
        } else {
            FragmentCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults.length != 1 || grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ErrorDialog.newInstance(getString(R.string.request_permission))
                        .show(getChildFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
            }
        } else {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }

    private void setUpCameraOutputs(int width, int height) {
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            for (String cameraId : manager.getCameraIdList()) {
                CameraCharacteristics characteristics
                        = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);

                // We don't use a front facing camera in this sample.
                Integer facing = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);
                if (facing != null && facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
                    continue;
                }

                StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(
                        CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
                if (map == null) {
                    continue;
                }


                Size largest = Collections.max(
                        Arrays.asList(map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG)),
                        new CompareSizesByArea());
                mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(largest.getWidth(), largest.getHeight(),
                        ImageFormat.JPEG, /*maxImages*/2);
                mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(
                        mOnImageAvailableListener, mBackgroundHandler);

                int displayRotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
                //noinspection ConstantConditions
                mSensorOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
                boolean swappedDimensions = false;
                switch (displayRotation) {
                    case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                    case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                        if (mSensorOrientation == 90 || mSensorOrientation == 270) {
                            swappedDimensions = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                    case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                        if (mSensorOrientation == 0 || mSensorOrientation == 180) {
                            swappedDimensions = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        Log.e(TAG, "Display rotation is invalid: " + displayRotation);
                }

                Point displaySize = new Point();
                activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(displaySize);
                int rotatedPreviewWidth = width;
                int rotatedPreviewHeight = height;
                int maxPreviewWidth = displaySize.x;
                int maxPreviewHeight = displaySize.y;

                if (swappedDimensions) {
                    rotatedPreviewWidth = height;
                    rotatedPreviewHeight = width;
                    maxPreviewWidth = displaySize.y;
                    maxPreviewHeight = displaySize.x;
                }

                if (maxPreviewWidth > MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH) {
                    maxPreviewWidth = MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH;
                }

                if (maxPreviewHeight > MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT) {
                    maxPreviewHeight = MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT;
                }

                mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class),
                        rotatedPreviewWidth, rotatedPreviewHeight, maxPreviewWidth,
                        maxPreviewHeight, largest);

                int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
                if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                    mTextureView.setAspectRatio(
                            mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
                } else {
                    mTextureView.setAspectRatio(
                            mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
                }

                Boolean available = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE);
                mFlashSupported = available == null ? false : available;

                mCameraId = cameraId;
                return;
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            ErrorDialog.newInstance(getString(R.string.camera_error))
                    .show(getChildFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
        }
    }

    private void openCamera(int width, int height) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestCameraPermission();
            return;
        }
        setUpCameraOutputs(width, height);
        configureTransform(width, height);
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            if (!mCameraOpenCloseLock.tryAcquire(2500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Time out waiting to lock camera opening.");
            }
            manager.openCamera(mCameraId, mStateCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera opening.", e);
        }
    }

    private void closeCamera() {
        try {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.acquire();
            if (null != mCaptureSession) {
                mCaptureSession.close();
                mCaptureSession = null;
            }
            if (null != mCameraDevice) {
                mCameraDevice.close();
                mCameraDevice = null;
            }
            if (null != mImageReader) {
                mImageReader.close();
                mImageReader = null;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera closing.", e);
        } finally {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
        }
    }

    private void startBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("CameraBackground");
        mBackgroundThread.start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
    }

    private void stopBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
        try {
            mBackgroundThread.join();
            mBackgroundThread = null;
            mBackgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void createCameraPreviewSession() {
        try {
            SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture != null;

            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());

            Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

            mPreviewRequestBuilder
                    = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);

            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface, mImageReader.getSurface()),
                    new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                            // The camera is already closed
                            if (null == mCameraDevice) {
                                return;
                            }

                            mCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                            try {
                                mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                                        CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                                setAutoFlash(mPreviewRequestBuilder);

                                mPreviewRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.build();
                                mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest,
                                        mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
                            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConfigureFailed(
                                @NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                            showToast("Failed");
                        }
                    }, null
            );
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void configureTransform(int viewWidth, int viewHeight) {
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (null == mTextureView || null == mPreviewSize || null == activity) {
            return;
        }
        int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
        RectF bufferRect = new RectF(0, 0, mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
        float centerX = viewRect.centerX();
        float centerY = viewRect.centerY();
        if (Surface.ROTATION_90 == rotation || Surface.ROTATION_270 == rotation) {
            bufferRect.offset(centerX - bufferRect.centerX(), centerY - bufferRect.centerY());
            matrix.setRectToRect(viewRect, bufferRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
            float scale = Math.max(
                    (float) viewHeight / mPreviewSize.getHeight(),
                    (float) viewWidth / mPreviewSize.getWidth());
            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
            matrix.postRotate(90 * (rotation - 2), centerX, centerY);
        } else if (Surface.ROTATION_180 == rotation) {
            matrix.postRotate(180, centerX, centerY);
        }
        mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);
    }

    private void takePicture() {
        lockFocus();
    }

    private void lockFocus() {
        try {

            mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER,
                    CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);
            // Tell #mCaptureCallback to wait for the lock.
            mState = STATE_WAITING_LOCK;
            mCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback,
                    mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void runPrecaptureSequence() {
        try {
            mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER,
                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER_START);

            mState = STATE_WAITING_PRECAPTURE;
            mCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback,
                    mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void captureStillPicture() {
        try {
            final Activity activity = getActivity();
            if (null == activity || null == mCameraDevice) {
                return;
            }
            final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder =
                    mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
            captureBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());

            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
            setAutoFlash(captureBuilder);

            int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, getOrientation(rotation));

            CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback CaptureCallback
                    = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                                               @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                               @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                    showToast("Saved: " + mFile);
                    Log.d(TAG, mFile.toString());
                    unlockFocus();
                }
            };

            mCaptureSession.stopRepeating();
            mCaptureSession.capture(captureBuilder.build(), CaptureCallback, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private int getOrientation(int rotation) {
        return (ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation) + mSensorOrientation + 270) % 360;
    }

    private void unlockFocus() {
        try {
            mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER,
                    CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_CANCEL);
            setAutoFlash(mPreviewRequestBuilder);
            mCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback,
                    mBackgroundHandler);
            mState = STATE_PREVIEW;
            mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest, mCaptureCallback,
                    mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.picture: {
                takePicture();
                break;
            }

        }
    }

    private void setAutoFlash(CaptureRequest.Builder requestBuilder) {
        if (mFlashSupported) {
            requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE,
                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);
        }
    }

    private static class ImageSaver implements Runnable {

        private final Image mImage;
        private final File mFile;

        public ImageSaver(Image image, File file) {
            mImage = image;
            mFile = file;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ByteBuffer buffer = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
            buffer.get(bytes);
            FileOutputStream output = null;
            try {
                output = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
                output.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                mImage.close();
                if (null != output) {
                    try {
                        output.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    static class CompareSizesByArea implements Comparator<Size> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {

            return Long.signum((long) lhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight() -
                    (long) rhs.getWidth() * rhs.getHeight());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: did the selected answer helped you? I´m facing the same problem

Comment: @Andrea sorry bro, actually I don't remember which trick i used for it. Please give it a try and see if it helps, and mark the answer...

Comment: Please read [this Medium article](https://medium.com/@kenodoggy/solving-image-rotation-on-android-using-camera2-api-7b3ed3518ab6) and especially the conclusions.

Comment: For me, the Medium article did not help. It seems that setting a value for `JPEG_ORIENTATION` is totally ignored, because the image in the `ImageReader` in `onImageAvailable` is *always* the same orientation

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the math in your getOrientation function is probably wrong.

See the sample code for the [JPEG_ORIENTATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult.html#JPEG_ORIENTATION) documentation:

```
private int getJpegOrientation(CameraCharacteristics c, int deviceOrientation) {
   if (deviceOrientation == android.view.OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) return 0;
   int sensorOrientation = c.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);

   // Round device orientation to a multiple of 90
   deviceOrientation = (deviceOrientation + 45) / 90 * 90;

   // Reverse device orientation for front-facing cameras
   boolean facingFront = c.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT;
   if (facingFront) deviceOrientation = -deviceOrientation;

   // Calculate desired JPEG orientation relative to camera orientation to make
   // the image upright relative to the device orientation
   int jpegOrientation = (sensorOrientation + deviceOrientation + 360) % 360;

   return jpegOrientation;
}
```

The odd mapping in your ORIENTATIONS table doesn't make it easy to read the code to make sure it matches the sample code, however.