# Camera2 API: orientation setting problems

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera2

I use Camera2 and ImageReader to get the image, after I display it on the screen. Regardless of the JPEG_ORIENTATION setting, the image is always rotated by -90 degrees.

I tried to change this value manually and using the methods from the documentation and examples. This is what happens on the phone and the emulator with android 9. But on android 5, the orientation changed correctly.

Displaying the image from the camera directly to the screen, as in [google sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) does not fit, the image must be processed. Bitmap rotation is too slow.

```
 private inner class CameraStateCallback : CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        override fun onOpened(camera: CameraDevice) {
            val builder = camera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW)
            val request = builder.apply {
                addTarget(outputSurface)
                set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, 90)
                set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE, Range(15, 15))
            }.build()
            camera.createCaptureSession(mutableListOf(outputSurface), SessionStateCallback(request), null)
        }

        override fun onDisconnected(camera: CameraDevice) {

        }

        override fun onError(camera: CameraDevice, error: Int) {

        }
    }

private inner class SessionStateCallback(private val request: CaptureRequest) : CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
        override fun onConfigureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession) {

        }

        override fun onConfigured(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
            this@CameraController.session = session
            session.setRepeatingRequest(request, null, null)
        }
    }
```

```
imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(1920, 1080, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1)
```

```
private val imageAvailableListener = {imageReader: ImageReader ->
        while(true) {
            val image = imageReader.acquireNextImage() ?: break
            val bytebuffer = image.planes[0].buffer
            val buffer = ByteArray(bytebuffer.capacity())
            bytebuffer.get(buffer)
            val bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buffer, 0, buffer.size, null)
            view.showCameraData(bmp)
            image.close()
        }
    }
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/38282076/192373#comment86683097_38282076

Comment: If you need to post-process the captured image, you can take into account that the jpeg may require rotation according to the [article](https://medium.com/@kenodoggy/solving-image-rotation-on-android-using-camera2-api-7b3ed3518ab6) cited above. But you can pass the image to an ImageView without rotation, by specifying the transform matrix instead.

Comment: As a last resort - yes, but I want to understand the cause of the problem.

Comment: The cause of the problem is that **cmaera2** api does not guarantee that your request of specific Jpeg orientation will be satisfied. [*Camera devices may either encode this value into the JPEG EXIF header, or rotate the image data to match this orientation.*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#JPEG_ORIENTATION)

Comment: @AlexCohn "camera2 api does not guarantee that your request of specific Jpeg orientation will be satisfied". Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: @DaveNottage that's my interpretation of what you find in the [link above](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#JPEG_ORIENTATION).