# How to rotate the preview of camera 90-degree on click of button in Camera2 API

Tags: android, android-camera2

I have a Camera2 API which is used to capture a image

**What is working:** I am able to capture image

**What I am trying to do:**

- My activity is fixed to portrait, now on click of a button how to
  change the preview from portrait to landscape
- Rotate the preview `90-degree`.

### **Is there a way to do it ?**

**Note**: I am not trying to rotate the captured image, I am trying to rotate the preview

---

**layout**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.android.camera.utils.AutoFitSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/view_finder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:foreground="@android:color/transparent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/capture_button"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="96dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_shutter"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/capture" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**AutoFitSurfaceView.kt**

```
class AutoFitSurfaceView @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
        defStyle: Int = 0
) : SurfaceView(context, attrs, defStyle) {

    private var aspectRatio = 0f

    /**
     * Sets the aspect ratio for this view. The size of the view will be
     * measured based on the ratio calculated from the parameters.
     *
     * @param width  Camera resolution horizontal size
     * @param height Camera resolution vertical size
     */
    fun setAspectRatio(width: Int, height: Int) {
        require(width > 0 && height > 0) { "Size cannot be negative" }
        aspectRatio = width.toFloat() / height.toFloat()
        holder.setFixedSize(width, height)
        requestLayout()
    }

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
        val width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)
        val height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec)
        if (aspectRatio == 0f) {
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height)
        } else {

            // Performs center-crop transformation of the camera frames
            val newWidth: Int
            val newHeight: Int
            val actualRatio = if (width > height) aspectRatio else 1f / aspectRatio
            if (width < height * actualRatio) {
                newHeight = height
                newWidth = (height * actualRatio).roundToInt()
            } else {
                newWidth = width
                newHeight = (width / actualRatio).roundToInt()
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "Measured dimensions set: $newWidth x $newHeight")
            setMeasuredDimension(newWidth, newHeight)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private val TAG = AutoFitSurfaceView::class.java.simpleName
    }
}
```

**CameraFragment.kt**

```
class CameraFragment : Fragment() {

    /** AndroidX navigation arguments */
    private val args: CameraFragmentArgs by navArgs()

    /** Host's navigation controller */
    private val navController: NavController by lazy {
        Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.fragment_container)
    }

    /** Detects, characterizes, and connects to a CameraDevice (used for all camera operations) */
    private val cameraManager: CameraManager by lazy {
        val context = requireContext().applicationContext
        context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
    }

    /** [CameraCharacteristics] corresponding to the provided Camera ID */
    private val characteristics: CameraCharacteristics by lazy {
        cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(args.cameraId)
    }

    /** Readers used as buffers for camera still shots */
    private lateinit var imageReader: ImageReader

    /** [HandlerThread] where all camera operations run */
    private val cameraThread = HandlerThread("CameraThread").apply { start() }

    /** [Handler] corresponding to [cameraThread] */
    private val cameraHandler = Handler(cameraThread.looper)

    /** Performs recording animation of flashing screen */
    private val animationTask: Runnable by lazy {
        Runnable {
            // Flash white animation
            overlay.background = Color.argb(150, 255, 255, 255).toDrawable()
            // Wait for ANIMATION_FAST_MILLIS
            overlay.postDelayed({
                // Remove white flash animation
                overlay.background = null
            }, CameraActivity.ANIMATION_FAST_MILLIS)
        }
    }

    /** [HandlerThread] where all buffer reading operations run */
    private val imageReaderThread = HandlerThread("imageReaderThread").apply { start() }

    /** [Handler] corresponding to [imageReaderThread] */
    private val imageReaderHandler = Handler(imageReaderThread.looper)

    /** Where the camera preview is displayed */
    private lateinit var viewFinder: AutoFitSurfaceView

    /** Overlay on top of the camera preview */
    private lateinit var overlay: View

    /** The [CameraDevice] that will be opened in this fragment */
    private lateinit var camera: CameraDevice

    /** Internal reference to the ongoing [CameraCaptureSession] configured with our parameters */
    private lateinit var session: CameraCaptureSession

    /** Live data listener for changes in the device orientation relative to the camera */
    private lateinit var relativeOrientation: OrientationLiveData

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false)

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        overlay = view.findViewById(R.id.overlay)
        viewFinder = view.findViewById(R.id.view_finder)

        viewFinder.holder.addCallback(object : SurfaceHolder.Callback {
            override fun surfaceDestroyed(holder: SurfaceHolder) = Unit

            override fun surfaceChanged(
                    holder: SurfaceHolder,
                    format: Int,
                    width: Int,
                    height: Int) = Unit

            override fun surfaceCreated(holder: SurfaceHolder) {

                // Selects appropriate preview size and configures view finder
                val previewSize = getPreviewOutputSize(
                        viewFinder.display, characteristics, SurfaceHolder::class.java)
                Log.d(TAG, "View finder size: ${viewFinder.width} x ${viewFinder.height}")
                Log.d(TAG, "Selected preview size: $previewSize")
                viewFinder.setAspectRatio(previewSize.width, previewSize.height)

                // To ensure that size is set, initialize camera in the view's thread
                view.post { initializeCamera() }
            }
        })

        // Used to rotate the output media to match device orientation
        relativeOrientation = OrientationLiveData(requireContext(), characteristics).apply {
            observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                orientation -> Log.d(TAG, "Orientation changed: $orientation")
            })
        }
    }

    /**
     * Begin all camera operations in a coroutine in the main thread. This function:
     * - Opens the camera
     * - Configures the camera session
     * - Starts the preview by dispatching a repeating capture request
     * - Sets up the still image capture listeners
     */
    private fun initializeCamera() = lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        // Open the selected camera
        camera = openCamera(cameraManager, args.cameraId, cameraHandler)

        // Initialize an image reader which will be used to capture still photos
        val size = characteristics.get(
                CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)!!
                .getOutputSizes(args.pixelFormat).maxBy { it.height * it.width }!!
        imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(
                size.width, size.height, args.pixelFormat, IMAGE_BUFFER_SIZE)

        // Creates list of Surfaces where the camera will output frames
        val targets = listOf(viewFinder.holder.surface, imageReader.surface)

        // Start a capture session using our open camera and list of Surfaces where frames will go
        session = createCaptureSession(camera, targets, cameraHandler)

        val captureRequest = camera.createCaptureRequest(
                CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW).apply { addTarget(viewFinder.holder.surface) }

        // This will keep sending the capture request as frequently as possible until the
        // session is torn down or session.stopRepeating() is called
        session.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequest.build(), null, cameraHandler)

        // Listen to the capture button
        capture_button.setOnClickListener {

            // Disable click listener to prevent multiple requests simultaneously in flight
            it.isEnabled = false

            // Perform I/O heavy operations in a different scope
            lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                takePhoto().use { result ->
                    Log.d(TAG, "Result received: $result")

                    // Save the result to disk
                    val output = saveResult(result)
                    Log.d(TAG, "Image saved: ${output.absolutePath}")

                    // If the result is a JPEG file, update EXIF metadata with orientation info
                    if (output.extension == "jpg") {
                        val exif = ExifInterface(output.absolutePath)
                        exif.setAttribute(
                                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, result.orientation.toString())
                        exif.saveAttributes()
                        Log.d(TAG, "EXIF metadata saved: ${output.absolutePath}")
                    }

                    // Display the photo taken to user
                    lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        navController.navigate(CameraFragmentDirections
                                .actionCameraToJpegViewer(output.absolutePath)
                                .setOrientation(result.orientation)
                                .setDepth(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q &&
                                        result.format == ImageFormat.DEPTH_JPEG))
                    }
                }

                // Re-enable click listener after photo is taken
                it.post { it.isEnabled = true }
            }
        }
    }

    /** Opens the camera and returns the opened device (as the result of the suspend coroutine) */
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private suspend fun openCamera(
            manager: CameraManager,
            cameraId: String,
            handler: Handler? = null
    ): CameraDevice = suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
        manager.openCamera(cameraId, object : CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
            override fun onOpened(device: CameraDevice) = cont.resume(device)

            override fun onDisconnected(device: CameraDevice) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Camera $cameraId has been disconnected")
                requireActivity().finish()
            }

            override fun onError(device: CameraDevice, error: Int) {
                val msg = when(error) {
                    ERROR_CAMERA_DEVICE -> "Fatal (device)"
                    ERROR_CAMERA_DISABLED -> "Device policy"
                    ERROR_CAMERA_IN_USE -> "Camera in use"
                    ERROR_CAMERA_SERVICE -> "Fatal (service)"
                    ERROR_MAX_CAMERAS_IN_USE -> "Maximum cameras in use"
                    else -> "Unknown"
                }
                val exc = RuntimeException("Camera $cameraId error: ($error) $msg")
                Log.e(TAG, exc.message, exc)
                if (cont.isActive) cont.resumeWithException(exc)
            }
        }, handler)
    }

    /**
     * Starts a [CameraCaptureSession] and returns the configured session (as the result of the
     * suspend coroutine
     */
    private suspend fun createCaptureSession(
            device: CameraDevice,
            targets: List<Surface>,
            handler: Handler? = null
    ): CameraCaptureSession = suspendCoroutine { cont ->

        // Create a capture session using the predefined targets; this also involves defining the
        // session state callback to be notified of when the session is ready
        device.createCaptureSession(targets, object: CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

            override fun onConfigured(session: CameraCaptureSession) = cont.resume(session)

            override fun onConfigureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
                val exc = RuntimeException("Camera ${device.id} session configuration failed")
                Log.e(TAG, exc.message, exc)
                cont.resumeWithException(exc)
            }
        }, handler)
    }

    /**
     * Helper function used to capture a still image using the [CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE]
     * template. It performs synchronization between the [CaptureResult] and the [Image] resulting
     * from the single capture, and outputs a [CombinedCaptureResult] object.
     */
    private suspend fun takePhoto():
            CombinedCaptureResult = suspendCoroutine { cont ->

        // Flush any images left in the image reader
        @Suppress("ControlFlowWithEmptyBody")
        while (imageReader.acquireNextImage() != null) {}

        // Start a new image queue
        val imageQueue = ArrayBlockingQueue<Image>(IMAGE_BUFFER_SIZE)
        imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener({ reader ->
            val image = reader.acquireNextImage()
            Log.d(TAG, "Image available in queue: ${image.timestamp}")
            imageQueue.add(image)
        }, imageReaderHandler)

        val captureRequest = session.device.createCaptureRequest(
                CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE).apply { addTarget(imageReader.surface) }
        session.capture(captureRequest.build(), object : CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

            override fun onCaptureStarted(
                    session: CameraCaptureSession,
                    request: CaptureRequest,
                    timestamp: Long,
                    frameNumber: Long) {
                super.onCaptureStarted(session, request, timestamp, frameNumber)
                viewFinder.post(animationTask)
            }

            override fun onCaptureCompleted(
                    session: CameraCaptureSession,
                    request: CaptureRequest,
                    result: TotalCaptureResult) {
                super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result)
                val resultTimestamp = result.get(CaptureResult.SENSOR_TIMESTAMP)
                Log.d(TAG, "Capture result received: $resultTimestamp")

                // Set a timeout in case image captured is dropped from the pipeline
                val exc = TimeoutException("Image dequeuing took too long")
                val timeoutRunnable = Runnable { cont.resumeWithException(exc) }
                imageReaderHandler.postDelayed(timeoutRunnable, IMAGE_CAPTURE_TIMEOUT_MILLIS)

                // Loop in the coroutine's context until an image with matching timestamp comes
                // We need to launch the coroutine context again because the callback is done in
                //  the handler provided to the `capture` method, not in our coroutine context
                @Suppress("BlockingMethodInNonBlockingContext")
                lifecycleScope.launch(cont.context) {
                    while (true) {

                        // Dequeue images while timestamps don't match
                        val image = imageQueue.take()
                        // TODO(owahltinez): b/142011420
                        // if (image.timestamp != resultTimestamp) continue
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q &&
                                image.format != ImageFormat.DEPTH_JPEG &&
                                image.timestamp != resultTimestamp) continue
                         Log.d(TAG, "Matching image dequeued: ${image.timestamp}")

                        // Unset the image reader listener
                        imageReaderHandler.removeCallbacks(timeoutRunnable)
                        imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(null, null)

                        // Clear the queue of images, if there are left
                        while (imageQueue.size > 0) {
                            imageQueue.take().close()
                        }

                        // Compute EXIF orientation metadata
                        val rotation = relativeOrientation.value ?: 0
                        val mirrored = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) ==
                                CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT
                        val exifOrientation = computeExifOrientation(rotation, mirrored)

                        // Build the result and resume progress
                        cont.resume(CombinedCaptureResult(
                                image, result, exifOrientation, imageReader.imageFormat))

                        // There is no need to break out of the loop, this coroutine will suspend
                    }
                }
            }
        }, cameraHandler)
    }

    /** Helper function used to save a [CombinedCaptureResult] into a [File] */
    private suspend fun saveResult(result: CombinedCaptureResult): File = suspendCoroutine { cont ->
        when (result.format) {

            // When the format is JPEG or DEPTH JPEG we can simply save the bytes as-is
            ImageFormat.JPEG, ImageFormat.DEPTH_JPEG -> {
                val buffer = result.image.planes[0].buffer
                val bytes = ByteArray(buffer.remaining()).apply { buffer.get(this) }
                try {
                    val output = createFile(requireContext(), "jpg")
                    FileOutputStream(output).use { it.write(bytes) }
                    cont.resume(output)
                } catch (exc: IOException) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to write JPEG image to file", exc)
                    cont.resumeWithException(exc)
                }
            }

            // When the format is RAW we use the DngCreator utility library
            ImageFormat.RAW_SENSOR -> {
                val dngCreator = DngCreator(characteristics, result.metadata)
                try {
                    val output = createFile(requireContext(), "dng")
                    FileOutputStream(output).use { dngCreator.writeImage(it, result.image) }
                    cont.resume(output)
                } catch (exc: IOException) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to write DNG image to file", exc)
                    cont.resumeWithException(exc)
                }
            }

            // No other formats are supported by this sample
            else -> {
                val exc = RuntimeException("Unknown image format: ${result.image.format}")
                Log.e(TAG, exc.message, exc)
                cont.resumeWithException(exc)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        try {
            camera.close()
        } catch (exc: Throwable) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error closing camera", exc)
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        cameraThread.quitSafely()
        imageReaderThread.quitSafely()
    }

    companion object {
        private val TAG = CameraFragment::class.java.simpleName

        /** Maximum number of images that will be held in the reader's buffer */
        private const val IMAGE_BUFFER_SIZE: Int = 3

        /** Maximum time allowed to wait for the result of an image capture */
        private const val IMAGE_CAPTURE_TIMEOUT_MILLIS: Long = 5000

        /** Helper data class used to hold capture metadata with their associated image */
        data class CombinedCaptureResult(
                val image: Image,
                val metadata: CaptureResult,
                val orientation: Int,
                val format: Int
        ) : Closeable {
            override fun close() = image.close()
        }

        /**
         * Create a [File] named a using formatted timestamp with the current date and time.
         *
         * @return [File] created.
         */
        private fun createFile(context: Context, extension: String): File {
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss_SSS", Locale.US)
            return File(context.filesDir, "IMG_${sdf.format(Date())}.$extension")
        }
    }
}
```

---

### {EDIT}

***Tried the solution*** [Alex Cohn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/192373/alex-cohn) suggested in one of the comments

```
viewFinder.setRotation(90)
```

Even though the preview area became landscape - But preview is not rotated

**Portrait**
[image]

**Landscape**
[image]

Comment: Do you want to switch the activity to landscape?

Comment: like how we rotate the image in crop ...similarly I am trying to rotate preview

Comment: have you tried `viewFinder.setRotation(90)`?

Comment: @AlexCohn ... Tried that, please check the edit in question .... preview area is landscape but not what we are viewing

Comment: OK then, you can try [matrix transform](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43506843/192373)

Comment: @AlexCohn ... I haven't used this before .... Can you show a snippet in my code I posted ..on how to use it as answer

Comment: The code can be found [here](https://github.com/googlearchive/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java#L740) but it needs some adaptation. I am not sure if **AutoFitSurfaceView** can be used for that. Maybe, its `onMeasure()` interferes with your use case, and it would be better to replace it with regular **SurfaceView**.

Comment: @AlexCohn ...That did solve my problem .... :) I stumbled on your comment ( https://stackoverflow.com/q/38282076/1083093 ) .... I read the medium article but couldn't resolve it on the image getting 90degree rotated on taken from portrait mode...How to solve this any input ?

Comment: As Brenda wrote there, *you are looking for code to copy/paste? There is no such snippet*. Because for the multitude of devices and use cases, there are too many tweaks you may or may not need. ***The bottom line is that the image capture (JPEG or RAW) will often come in its native orientation, but the size of this image may be too much to allow rotation (essentially, transcoding) at full resolution.***